# Trouble while importing JSON Data to App.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, import, node-fetch

I have to pass JSON data from **Data.js** to **App.js**. If I `console.log` data in **Data.js** everything is okay, however when I try to pass it for using in cards it shows me this **Error**.

[image: Error]

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { Card, Button, Container, Row } from "react-bootstrap";
import "./styles.css";
import Data from "./components/Data";

function createCard(item) {
  return (
    <Card style={{ width: "18rem" }}>
      <Card.Img variant="top" src="" />
      <Card.Body>
        <Card.Title>{item.name}</Card.Title>
        <Card.Text>Kod: {item.article} </Card.Text>
        <Button variant="primary">{item.salePrices[0].value / 100}AZN</Button>
      </Card.Body>
    </Card>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Container>
        <Row className="justify-content-md-center">{Data.map(createCard)}</Row>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Data.js**

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
var options = {
    headers: {
       'Authorization': 'Basic ' + loginPassword
    }   
 };

 (async () => {
   const response = await fetch(url, options);
   const data = await response.json(); 

})();
 
export default data;
```

**P.S.** Two moments which in my opinion can help to solve this problem.

**First** is when I try to console.log data outside of the async function it doesn't work, so that means I can reach the value only inside of that async function.

The **second** moment is when I add `const test = "1";` to data.js and try to pass it `export default test;` to App.js it also shows the same error as I mentioned before.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am not sure about it but can you please check spellings because you exported `data` and imported `Data` javascript is case sensitive

Comment: @DevChaudhary It is a default export so it shouldn't matter

Comment: Can you try this approach - use `useState` for storing data and `useEffect` for fetching data...It is preferred way of fetching data in React

Comment: Thanks for your response. I already checked by doing all "data" words with a capitalized letter, nothing changes. I think the problem should be a bit deeper than a simple typo.

Comment: It wouldn't work anyway because `data` is scoped to the async function.

Comment: @Andy So, how I should save data to use it in App?

Comment: `data` isn't a component. Don't confuse the two.

Comment: @Andy Then should I somehow transform it into a component before I use it in App?

Comment: Based on your code you (maybe) have a node server, and a React app running in the browser. Somehow those two need to connect with each other. Add an endpoint to the server that the app can reach out to and get the data, and then set the state in the app with the data that's delivered.

Answer (score 0):

This is bcause the data is not yet fetched in the file and you exported that. You don't even need data.js. Try this code in your app.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Card, Button, Container, Row } from "react-bootstrap";
import fetch from "node-fetch";

function createCard(item) {
  return (
    <Card style={{ width: "18rem" }}>
      <Card.Img variant="top" src="" />
      <Card.Body>
        <Card.Title>{item.id}</Card.Title>
        <Card.Text>Kod: {item.title} </Card.Text>
        <Button variant="primary">{item.salePrices[0].value / 100}AZN</Button>
      </Card.Body>
    </Card>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  const getData = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(url, options);
    const Data = await response.json();
    setData(Data);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Container>
        <Row className="justify-content-md-center">
          {data && data.map(createCard)}
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here getData is your async call of data.js. If you want modularity in your code and want that async call in another file then you need to import the promise from data.js file instead of data and resolve it in app.js file.